# SSRS expression error

Tags: reporting-services

Basically I converted this Crystal Report formula

```
if ucas({?Trade Buy or Sell}) = "Trade Buy" 
then "IOSW_BUY_01" 
else if ucase({?Trade Buy or Sell})="Trade Sell" then IOSW_SELL_02.
```

To:

```
SSRS -IIF(Fields!TradeBuyorSell.Value="Trade Buy","IOSW_BUY_01", 
IIF(Fields!TradeBuyorSell.Value="Trade Sell","IOSW_SELL_02"))
```

However, I am getting the below error message

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> [rsCompilerErrorInExpression]The value expression for the textrun 'TradeBuyorSell.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0] contains an
>   error :[BC30455]Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart'of
>   Public Function IIF(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object,
>   FalsePart As Object) As Object'

Please assist this is very urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner IIF is missing the second, "false" part of the function.

```
IIF(Fields!TradeBuyorSell.Value="Trade Buy","IOSW_BUY_01", IIF(Fields!TradeBuyorSell.Value="Trade Sell","IOSW_SELL_02", **************))
```

Replace ************** with the value that needs to go there.

Comment: Basically I am trying to convert this crystal report formula if ucas({?Trade Buy or Sell}) = "Trade Buy" then "IOSW_BUY_01" else if ucase({?Trade Buy or Sell})="Trade Sell" then IOSW_SELL_02.